# Figuring out if electrical components are connected in series or parallel (just by looking at circuit diagram)

Tags: electric-circuits

Is there a way to find out if a set of electrical components within a given circuit are in parallel/series just by looking at the circuit diagram. If so, can someone give the rules to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If two elements in a circuit are connected “end to end” so that all of the current which passes through one must pass through the other, then they are in series.  If they are connected “side by side” so that the current is divided between them, they are in parallel.  The joker is a “bridge”:  two in series, side by side with two more in series, and a fifth element connecting the mid-points.

Answer (score 0):

If elements between two poins all have the same current passing through them, they are in series.
$V=\sum I_i R_i$ and all $I_i$ are the same so $V=I\sum R_i$.

If they all have the same voltage across them, they are in parallel.  $I=\sum {V_i \over R_1}$ and all $V_i$ are the same so $I=V\sum {1 \over R_i}$

If neither of the above is true then you just go back to Kirchoff's Laws.